# Smooth fonts in Gentoo terminal in Awesome WM?

Tags: linux, terminal, gentoo, gnome-terminal, awesome-wm

I had GNOME DE but recently I've switched to Awesome WM.
The only problem I have I can't set smooth fonts in Gnome-terminal.
If I start gnome-settings-daemon, all the fonts in terminal become smooth, but is it possible to make it work without gnome-settings-daemon?
I would change the terminal if in another smooth fonts were.

My ~/.fonts.conf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>

<!-- Give all fonts light hinting and subpixel smoothing -->
<!--
<match target="font">
    <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
        <const>rgb</const>
    </edit>
    <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
        <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
    <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
        <const>hintslight</const>
    </edit>
    <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
        <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
</match>
-->

<!--
     <match target="font">
        <test qual="all" name="rgba"><const>unknown</const></test>
           <edit name="rgba" mode="assign"><const>rgb</const></edit>
     </match>
-->

<!--  Do not smooth Fixedsys  -->
<match target="font">
    <test name="family">
        <string>FixedsysTTF</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="antialias">
        <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
</match>

<!--  Do not smooth Tahoma 8pt and under  -->
<match target="font">
    <test name="family">
        <string>Tahoma</string>
    </test>
    <test compare="less" name="size" qual="any">
        <double>9</double>
    </test>
    <edit name="antialias">
        <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
</match>

<!--  Do not smooth Times New Roman or Courier New for 12pt and under  -->
<match target="font">
    <test name="family">
        <string>Times New Roman</string>
    </test>
    <test compare="less" name="size" qual="any">
        <double>13</double>
    </test>
    <edit name="antialias">
        <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
</match>

<match target="font">
    <test name="family">
        <string>Courier</string>
        <string>Courier New</string>
        <string>Courier 10 Pitch</string>
    </test>
    <test compare="less" name="size" qual="any">
        <double>11</double>
    </test>
    <edit name="antialias">
        <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
</match>

<!-- Do not autohint Courier New, Fixedsys, Tahoma, or Times New Roman -->
<match target="font">
    <test name="family">
        <string>Courier New</string>
        <string>Times New Roman</string>
        <string>Tahoma</string>
        <string>FixedsysTTF</string>
    </test>
    <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
        <const>hintslight</const>
    </edit>
    <edit mode="assign" name="autohint">
        <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
</match>

<match target="pattern">
            <test qual="any" name="family">
                    <string>Bitstream Vera Sans</string>
            </test>
            <edit name="family" mode="assign">
                    <string>Arial</string>
            </edit>
</match>
    <match target="pattern">
            <test qual="any" name="family">
                    <string>Helvetica</string>
            </test>
            <edit name="family" mode="assign">
                    <string>Arial</string>
            </edit>
</match>
<match target="pattern">
            <test qual="any" name="family">
                    <string>Palatino</string>
            </test>
            <edit name="family" mode="assign">
                    <string>Georgia</string>
            </edit>
</match>
</fontconfig>
```

~/.gtkrc-2.0

```
include "/usr/share/themes/Human/gtk-2.0/gtkrc" gtk-can-change-accels = 1

gtk-theme-name = "Human" gtk-icon-theme-name = "Human" gtk-font-name = "Ubuntu 12"

gtk-xft-antialias = 1 gtk-xft-hinting
= 1 gtk-xft-hintstyle = "hintslight" gtk-xft-rgba = "rgb"
```

~/.Xresorces

```
Xft.dpi: 96.0
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
Xft.antialias: true
Xft.rgba: none
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this sounds flippant, but you *could* switch to a different terminal (say, the one that comes with XFCE).  The reason I suggest this is because, AFAIK, gnome-terminal **only** takes its settings from gnome-settings-daemon.

Another way of fixing it might be to run xsettingsd: https://code.google.com/p/xsettingsd/

It's supposed to be a drop-in replacement for gnome-settings-daemon.  I'm running it, but since I don't really run many GNOME apps, I can't say for sure that it actually works (mostly, I set it up once a long time ago, and, since it doesn't really use that much resources, I just leave it alone).

Answer (score 1):

You can install `strace` and run `strance gnome-settings-daemon`.

Check the output and find what gnome-settings-daemon are doing to change the fonts, create a small subset of it in another programming language.
DONE!